# Facebook Authentication AccesToken

Tags: facebook-access-token

I need help in Accesstoken generation.
Currently Im integrating facebook Ad into our application using Facebook Api for that I have created Facebook App in my Facebook Developer account and client account is added to this Inorder to push Ad to their account.
Currently Im generating Accesstoken using developer account for which  expiration time is not there .Can we use this AccessToken for long

Comment: how long? it'll definitely expire ...

Comment: Since its in developers accounts. Accesstoken generated using developers account will not expire.Is this true.